# How to change icons that Visual Studio 2022 is using?

Tags: visual-studio, customization, visual-studio-2022

How can i change the icons that the IDE is using? In particular, I do not like how inheritance margin icons look like, and I was wondering what's the way to change them.
[example inheritance margin icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzFKr.png)

I've tried googling it, but it always gets confused either with visual studio code or the dev application icon

Comment: That's not possible.  Use Help > Send Feedback to let them know.